# I can't select an object unless I click its path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't select an object unless I click its path. How can I undo that?  "Object selection by path only" is unchecked.

Comment: Is it possible the object has no fill? or maybe you have the outline view on?

Comment: Perhaps it has been placed outside the artboard and you have "trim view" turned on.  This one catches me out all the time.

Comment: How is the object made? Is the object a path with a thick stroke perhaps?  If so, you will need to click its path to select it, or click and drag to select it with the Selection Tool, or you could use the Lasso Tool.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s just one particular object, it might be an empty clipping mask, which you can release in the Object menu.

Answer (score 0):

Click its selection flag in the Layers panel. It's a way to select parts inside a group or under other objects.